# How to combine many query in spreadsheet if one or more query is empty

Tags: mysql, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas

**Problem**
I have some data from spreadsheet and want to match with date with query, and combine many query.

**Question**
My query will work if all col i choose is'nt empty. But my data (col) will not all be filled, some will be left blank. If I try with my query one data blank don't want to appear.

**Example**

```js
=IFERROR({IFERROR(QUERY(dashboar_data;"SELECT C,I WHERE J = date'" & TEXT(DATEVALUE(B5);"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'";0);dashboar_data/0); 
          IFERROR(QUERY(dashboar_data;"SELECT C,M WHERE N = date'" & TEXT(DATEVALUE(B5);"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'";0);dashboar_data/0); 
          IFERROR(QUERY(dashboar_data;"SELECT C,Q WHERE R = date'" & TEXT(DATEVALUE(B5);"yyyy-mm-dd") & "'";0);dashboar_data/0)})
```

Its will work if 3 col is filled, i want if one col empty other query still work

Comment: Hello, could you please provide some more details? Like what error you are getting and some sample data from your spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

You may try to fake data with iferror. Produce the same number of columns with empty values:

`iferror (... , {""\""})`

Comment: still didn't work :(